# How to publish Telegram instant view template for review

Tags: telegram

I created an Telegram IV template from my website. All checks are green and the template is working fine when published through:

> https://t.me/iv?url=example.com

How can I publish my template for approval? so any URL from:

> https://example.com

will be considered as Instant View in Telegram?

Comment: Any news about publishing IV templates?

Comment: Any news about publishing IV templates?

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug? I think it describes your problem https://bugs.telegram.org/c/21634

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instant View only support few domain for now, I think they will accept templates after [contest](https://instantview.telegram.org/contest/).

Comment: No official reference, but I am contest participant, and got same response from Supporter.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. It looks like currently you need to publish your template through the contest ([this page](https://instantview.telegram.org/my)).

1. Mark as 'Tracked' in an editor as minimum 10 of articles/posts on your site. If each one is successful, do the follow.
2. Press button 'Submit template'.

Comment: Does it actually work, I mean, if you do the template not because of the contest but for your website - does it even have a chance to get accepted?

Comment: No, it does not  work.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, it doesn't seem that Telegram is opening Instant View to more domains. I have tried to publish / submit a template plenty times, with no success.

On [My templates](https://instantview.telegram.org/my/) page, clicking Submit Template, then Confirm, does nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.telegram.org/c/21634

Answer (score 1):

> **Publishing templates**
>
> If the Instant View page has been processed successfully, you'll see a
> View in Telegram button in the top right corner – you can use it to
> view the resulting page in-app.
>
> **For your own audience**
>
> Note that if you send the resulting t.me/iv?url=...&rhash=... link to
> other Telegram users, they will see an Instant View page built using
> your template (the rhash parameter in the link determines which
> template is used to create the page). This means that, as a website
> owner, you can create a template for your page and publish
> t.me/iv?url=... links with the corresponding rhash to your Telegram
> channel — and your subscribers will be able to view your articles in
> the Instant View format right away.
>
> **For all Telegram users**
>
> If you'd like your template to become truly public and seen by all
> users, regardless of the link they get, the template will need to be
> approved by the Telegram team.
>
> ― https://instantview.telegram.org/#publishing-templates

The problem is that there is not documentation about how "*the template will [...] be approved by the Telegram team*" when there are no contests.

Comment: You've missed the point. `the template will need to be approved by the Telegram team.` - that's the key here and no one ever know how to get it approved for your own website (without millions of users)

Comment: how long i should wait telegram team approve IV?

Comment: @ReinierHernández I think Telegram will just do nothing for your Instant Views (2022).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (2022) it seems it's not possible to submit an InstantView template for review. The support said to me it's only possible if there is an ongoing context.

This is strange, since in the interface says that it's possible to submit a template without participating to a context:

[image: Telegram Instant View context pop-up]

If you confirm, the web page tries to send the template in a context (see `sendToContest`):

```
POST https://instantview.telegram.org/api/my?hash=<omissis>
section=<domain>&method=sendToContest
```

The request fails without any human error. I think it's a bug in the Instant View submission platform, that does not work without a context.

Here a bug report related to "Cannot submit InstantView":

https://bugs.telegram.org/c/21634

Comment: I believe that Telegram team got bored developing that feature and started working on something else.

Comment: Yeah. In that case they could make the server Open Source and let the community propose fixes, with at least one active maintainer coordinating the repository, instead of dedicating their small elected set of developers now concentrated in another part of Telegram.